# Is it possible for a method that returns a primitive type to return null?

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I am practicing with `ArrayList` and have come up against something I don't understand. I have a class `Knapsack` and a class `Item`, I am filling up the `knapsacks` with `items` and performing various tests on the `knapsacks` etc.

One of the public `Knapsack` methods returns the total weight of the `non-null` items in the `knapsack`. Another `Knapsack` method which is a static class method returns the heaviest `knapsack` in an array of `Knapsack` objects.

When I call this code to test if the Items in the `knapsack` are equal to 1000g:

```
testIntEqual("heaviestKnapsack", 1000, Knapsack.heaviestKnapsack(sacks).totalWeightInGrammes());
```

IntelliJ gives me a `NullPointerException` warning for the call `totalWeightInGrammes()`

Here are the implementations of the `heaviestKnapsack()` and `totalWeightInGrammes()` methods:

```
public static Knapsack heaviestKnapsack(Knapsack[] knapsacks) {
    // TO DO
    if (knapsacks.length != 0) {
        Knapsack heaviest;
        int index = 0;
        while (true) {
            heaviest = knapsacks[index];
            if (heaviest == null) {
                index++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (Knapsack knapsack : knapsacks) {
            if (knapsack != null && (getTotalKnapsackWeight(knapsack) > getTotalKnapsackWeight(heaviest))) {
                heaviest = knapsack;
            }
        }
        return heaviest;
    }
    return null;
}

public int totalWeightInGrammes() {
    // TO DO
    if (!knapsackItems.isEmpty()) {
        int totalWeight = 0;
        for (Item i : knapsackItems) {
            if (i != null) {
                totalWeight += i.getWeightInGrammes();
            }
        }
        return totalWeight;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am really confused as to why IntelliJ is warning me about NPE when I have tested thoroughly for `null` in these methods and `totalWeightInGrammes()` returns the primitive type `int`.

Many thanks for all comments :)

Comment: Does it actually cause a NPE when you run it, or is it just the IDE complaining?

Comment: Just the IDE complaining, it compiles and runs fine

Comment: Isn't the NPE warning for the method `heaviestKnapsack` which can return null?

Comment: In method totalWeightInGrammes you check if knapsackItems is not empty. Are you sure there is no chance that this item may be null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Knapsack.heaviestKnapsack(sacks).totalWeightInGrammes()
         ^^^^                    ^^^^ 
     can return null          NPE warning
```

You have a `NPE warning` on `.totalWeightInGrammes()` because `heaviestKnapsack()` can return `null`, so it will be the call to `.totalWeightInGrammes()` that will throw the `NPE`

Comment: I was thinking that it would have to be a method that returned an object, that was why I was getting confused. So how would I "null proof" my heaviestKnapsack() method anymore? I thought I'd done enough

Comment: @PumpkinBreath it'll be `null proof` if the method never return `null` value, you can't do other way

Comment: Ok guys sorry I've seen what's going on. I've set the method to return null in the event that the array is empty! Can't believe I've gone to all this trouble over this....

Comment: If all knapsacks in the array are null, the while-loop will cause an IndexOutOfBounds exception. And actually that loop really serves no useful purpose; it can all be done in a single loop.

Comment: @PumpkinBreath If you consider this post as ended and answered, please accept the answer, if not comment to give further answer